# Jooq autogenerate results in "SELECT command denied to user ... for table 'proc'

Tags: java, sql, heroku, jooq, cleardb

I am having issues while trying to run a Jooq autogenerate gradle task that takes table infos from a cleardb cloud based database.

The error i get is below and has apparently something to do with the fact that i have limited access to the clearDB cloud service. In short, the script asks to see the content of proc - which holds all the procedures that I might have stored on the remote DB. The thing is that I do not use procedure and I wish to have this operation ignored completely.

is there a way to tell jooq autogeneration to not query PROC?

```
Error while fetching functions
org.jooq.exception.DataAccessException: SQL [select `mysql`.`proc`.`db`, `mysql`.`proc`.`name`, `mysql`.`proc`.`comment`, `mysql`.`proc`.`param_list`, `mysql`.`proc`.`returns` from `mysql`.`proc` where `mysql`.`proc`.`db` in (?) order by `mysql`.`proc`.`db` asc, `mysql`.`proc`.`name` asc]; **SELECT command denied to user 'b******4'@'ip-**-**-**-**.ec2.internal' for table 'proc'**
    at org.jooq.impl.Utils.translate(Utils.java:1078)
    at org.jooq.impl.DefaultExecuteContext.sqlException(DefaultExecuteContext.java:462)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:302)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.fetch(AbstractResultQuery.java:319)
    at org.jooq.impl.SelectImpl.fetch(SelectImpl.java:1024)
    at org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase.getRoutines0(MySQLDatabase.java:306)
    at org.jooq.util.AbstractDatabase.getRoutines(AbstractDatabase.java:629)
    at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generate(JavaGenerator.java:241)
    at org.jooq.util.JavaGenerator.generate(JavaGenerator.java:174)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.run(GenerationTool.java:291)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool.main(GenerationTool.java:135)
    at org.jooq.util.GenerationTool$main.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at build_25tutouf1gvhdgaqpfank74rq6$_run_closure7.doCall(/home/jes/Development/git/bjdata/build.gradle:126)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:272)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:425)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:502)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$ClosureTaskAction.execute(AbstractTask.java:483)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskStatusNagger$1.execute(TaskStatusNagger.java:77)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.TaskStatusNagger$1.execute(TaskStatusNagger.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:289)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$1.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:198)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultCacheAccess.java:266)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.longRunningOperation(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:135)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.changedetection.state.DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.longRunningOperation(DefaultTaskArtifactStateCacheAccess.java:95)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:31)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:86)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:67)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:166)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:113)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:81)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:42)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:24)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartStopIfBuildAndStop.execute(StartStopIfBuildAndStop.java:33)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ReturnResult.execute(ReturnResult.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:71)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:69)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:45)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator.runCommand(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:186)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.doBuild(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HandleStop.execute(HandleStop.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonHygieneAction.execute(DaemonHygieneAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.execute(CatchAndForwardDaemonFailure.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:125)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.executeCommand(DefaultDaemonCommandExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.handleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:155)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.receiveAndHandleCommand(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:128)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler$ConnectionWorker.run(DefaultIncomingConnectionHandler.java:116)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.DefaultExecutorFactory$StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(DefaultExecutorFactory.java:64)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: SELECT command denied to user 'b*********4'@'ip-**-**-**-**.ec2.internal' for table 'proc'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4237)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4169)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2617)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2778)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2834)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2156)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1379)
    at org.jooq.tools.jdbc.DefaultPreparedStatement.execute(DefaultPreparedStatement.java:189)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractResultQuery.execute(AbstractResultQuery.java:250)
    at org.jooq.impl.AbstractQuery.execute(AbstractQuery.java:298)
    ... 104 more
```

and the configuration used to generate the whole thing with jooq is:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://www.jooq.org/xsd/jooq-codegen-3.0.0.xsd">
    <jdbc>
        <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
        <url>jdbc:mysql://us-cdbr-east-**.cleardb.net/heroku_******</url>
        <user>b***********4</user>
        <password>***********</password>
    </jdbc>
    <generator>
        <name>org.jooq.util.DefaultGenerator</name>
        <database>
            <name>org.jooq.util.mysql.MySQLDatabase</name>
            <includes>.*</includes>
            <excludes></excludes>
            <recordVersionFields></recordVersionFields>
            <recordTimestampFields></recordTimestampFields>
            <dateAsTimestamp>false</dateAsTimestamp>
            <unsignedTypes>true</unsignedTypes>
            <inputSchema>heroku_*****</inputSchema>
        </database>
        <generate>
            <relations>true</relations>
            <deprecated>true</deprecated>
            <instanceFields>true</instanceFields>
            <generatedAnnotation>true</generatedAnnotation>
            <records>true</records>
            <pojos>false</pojos>
            <immutablePojos>false</immutablePojos>
            <interfaces>false</interfaces>
            <daos>false</daos>
            <jpaAnnotations>false</jpaAnnotations>
            <validationAnnotations>false</validationAnnotations>
            <globalObjectReferences>true</globalObjectReferences>
        </generate>
        <target>
            <packageName>***********.entities.generated</packageName>
            <directory>/***********/src/main/java/</directory>
        </target>
    </generator>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue ([#2958](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2958)) was fixed in jOOQ 3.3.0 and in 3.2.3 ([#2960](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2960)). I suggest upgrading...

More background infos in this thread: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/WpUnYQSDIlY